# Overflow when converting int to datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, tsql

I'm currently importing a table from MYSQL to MSSQL. There's a column there for storing date, only it's stored as an number. When i import it to MSSQL i get it in as an int data type.

When i try to convert that to datetime I get an :

> Arithmetic overflow error converting
>   expression to data type datetime.

Since i'm using MSSQL 2005 I can't use datetime2 and fit it so it does not overflow.

Is there a way to trim that date stored as an int so it does not overflow the datetime format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MSSQL *datetime* data type can take values from January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999.  The integer equivalents for those values are -53690 and 2958463 respectively.  Trying to convert integer values outside that range would cause the arithmetic overflow.